# Proof-of-concept HTTP to HTTP stunnel?

Tags: stunnel

Similar to this [*Simple proof-of-concept stunnel configuration*](https://superuser.com/questions/794982/simple-proof-of-concept-stunnel-configuration), except mine should be even simpler, as I don't need any HTTPS or SSL.

I need to configure `stunnel` to proxy HTTP requests from a custom port on my VPS to http://84.33.37.101/, a plain HTTP IPv4 looking glass page.

My `/etc/stunnel/stunnel.conf`:

```
; It is recommended to drop root privileges if stunnel is started by root
setuid = stunnel4
setgid = stunnel4

; PID file is created inside the chroot jail (if enabled)
pid = /var/run/stunnel/stunnel.pid

; Debugging stuff (may be useful for troubleshooting)
foreground = yes
debug = debug
output = /var/log/stunnel4/stunnel.log

; Test
[http-test]
client = yes
accept = 48080
connect = 84.33.37.101:80
```

When I visit `http://MY-VPS-IP:48080` in my browser, I get:

```
2023.10.13 14:29:33 LOG7[ui]: Clients allowed=500
2023.10.13 14:29:33 LOG5[ui]: stunnel 5.39 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu platform
2023.10.13 14:29:33 LOG5[ui]: Compiled with OpenSSL 1.1.0c  10 Nov 2016
2023.10.13 14:29:33 LOG5[ui]: Running  with OpenSSL 1.1.0l  10 Sep 2019
2023.10.13 14:29:33 LOG5[ui]: Update OpenSSL shared libraries or rebuild stunnel
2023.10.13 14:29:33 LOG5[ui]: Threading:PTHREAD Sockets:POLL,IPv6,SYSTEMD TLS:ENGINE,FIPS,OCSP,PSK,SNI Auth:LIBWRAP
2023.10.13 14:29:33 LOG7[ui]: errno: (*__errno_location ())
2023.10.13 14:29:33 LOG5[ui]: Reading configuration from file /etc/stunnel/stunnel.conf
2023.10.13 14:29:33 LOG5[ui]: UTF-8 byte order mark detected
2023.10.13 14:29:33 LOG5[ui]: FIPS mode disabled
2023.10.13 14:29:33 LOG7[ui]: Compression disabled
2023.10.13 14:29:33 LOG7[ui]: Snagged 64 random bytes from /root/.rnd
2023.10.13 14:29:33 LOG7[ui]: Wrote 1024 new random bytes to /root/.rnd
2023.10.13 14:29:33 LOG7[ui]: PRNG seeded successfully
2023.10.13 14:29:33 LOG6[ui]: Initializing service [http-test]
2023.10.13 14:29:33 LOG7[ui]: No certificate or private key specified
2023.10.13 14:29:33 LOG4[ui]: Service [http-test] needs authentication to prevent MITM attacks
2023.10.13 14:29:33 LOG7[ui]: TLS options: 0x02020004 (+0x02000000, -0x00000000)
2023.10.13 14:29:33 LOG5[ui]: Configuration successful
2023.10.13 14:29:33 LOG7[ui]: Listening file descriptor created (FD=7)
2023.10.13 14:29:33 LOG7[ui]: Option SO_REUSEADDR set on accept socket
2023.10.13 14:29:33 LOG7[ui]: Service [http-test] (FD=7) bound to 0.0.0.0:48080
2023.10.13 14:29:33 LOG7[cron]: Cron thread initialized
2023.10.13 14:29:33 LOG6[cron]: Executing cron jobs
2023.10.13 14:29:33 LOG6[cron]: Cron jobs completed in 0 seconds
2023.10.13 14:29:33 LOG7[cron]: Waiting 86400 seconds
2023.10.13 14:29:33 LOG7[ui]: Created pid file /var/run/stunnel/stunnel.pid
2023.10.13 14:30:04 LOG7[ui]: Found 1 ready file descriptor(s)
2023.10.13 14:30:04 LOG7[ui]: FD=4 events=0x2001 revents=0x0
2023.10.13 14:30:04 LOG7[ui]: FD=7 events=0x2001 revents=0x1
2023.10.13 14:30:04 LOG7[ui]: Service [http-test] accepted (FD=3) from MY-PC-IP:49897
2023.10.13 14:30:04 LOG7[0]: Service [http-test] started
2023.10.13 14:30:04 LOG7[0]: Option TCP_NODELAY set on local socket
2023.10.13 14:30:04 LOG5[0]: Service [http-test] accepted connection from MY-PC:49897
2023.10.13 14:30:04 LOG6[0]: s_connect: connecting 84.33.37.101:80
2023.10.13 14:30:04 LOG7[0]: s_connect: s_poll_wait 84.33.37.101:80: waiting 10 seconds
2023.10.13 14:30:04 LOG5[0]: s_connect: connected 84.33.37.101:80
2023.10.13 14:30:04 LOG5[0]: Service [http-test] connected remote server from MY-VPS-IP:36584
2023.10.13 14:30:04 LOG7[0]: Option TCP_NODELAY set on remote socket
2023.10.13 14:30:04 LOG7[0]: Remote descriptor (FD=9) initialized
2023.10.13 14:30:04 LOG6[0]: SNI: sending servername: 84.33.37.101
2023.10.13 14:30:04 LOG6[0]: Peer certificate not required
2023.10.13 14:30:04 LOG7[0]: TLS state (connect): before SSL initialization
2023.10.13 14:30:04 LOG7[0]: TLS state (connect): SSLv3/TLS write client hello
2023.10.13 14:30:04 LOG3[0]: SSL_connect: 1408F10B: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
2023.10.13 14:30:04 LOG5[0]: Connection reset: 0 byte(s) sent to TLS, 0 byte(s) sent to socket
2023.10.13 14:30:04 LOG7[0]: Deallocating application specific data for addr index
2023.10.13 14:30:04 LOG7[0]: Remote descriptor (FD=9) closed
2023.10.13 14:30:04 LOG7[0]: Local descriptor (FD=3) closed
2023.10.13 14:30:04 LOG7[0]: Service [http-test] finished (0 left)
```

Nowhere in my config I mention SSL or 443, so why does `stunnel` keep bringing it up? Is there any way to disable it?

**UPD** I tried this against my other VPS and I see this in it's Apache Webserver logs:

```
MY-VPS-IP - - [13/Oct/2023:12:13:24 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01" 400 512 "-" "-"
```

According to [HTTP requests "\x80z\x01\x03\x01" in my Apache logs](https://serverfault.com/questions/390013/http-requests-x80z-x01-x03-x01-in-my-apache-logs), "*It looks like someone tries to connect via ssl to non-ssl port*".

Comment: In principle, HTTP in stunnel **is** HTTPS. It probably expects that your browser use `https://...` to connect to a stunnel.

Comment: Why are you using stunnel to proxy http, which is not TLS?

Comment: Because I believed `stunnel` can tunnel anything regardless of whether it's TLS. But apparently it can not?

Comment: why don't you use a reverse proxy?

Comment: "The stunnel program is designed to work as TLS encryption wrapper between remote clients and local (inetd-startable) or remote servers. The concept is that having non-TLS aware daemons running on your system you can easily set them up to communicate with clients over secure TLS channels."

Comment: stunnel can do exactly two things: convert a plaintext connection to an SSL/TLS connection (e.g. HTTP to HTTPS) or convert SSL/TLS to plaintext (e.g. HTTPS to HTTP). If you put _two_ of those back-to-back you get a tunnel: (client) HTTP to HTTPS to HTTP (server). If you don't want any SSL or HTTPS, you don't want stunnel. If you want to relay a plaintext (HTTP) connection, socat can do that, but it's not any kind of tunnel.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 thanks again, please post this comment as an answer as well so I can accept it too